# I changed disk limit of rabbitmq and now can't restart it.

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I am very new to rabbitMQ. I get getting disk limit full error so I thought of changing the disk limit. I executed following command in sequence:

```
#1. rabbitmqctl set_disk_free_limit 1GB
#2. sudo systemctl stop rabbitmq-server.service
#3. sudo systemctl disable rabbitmq-server.service
#4. sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service  --> failing
```

I saw rabbitmq process was still running (by using top command). So I executed following:

```
#5. sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
#6 sudo service rabbitmq-server start --> failing
```

I am getting following error:

```
> Jul 11 15:13:37 sk-backend-vm rabbitmq-server[31810]:              
> Starting broker... Jul 11 15:13:40 sk-backend-vm
> rabbitmq-server[31810]: erl_child_setup closed Jul 11 15:13:40
> sk-backend-vm rabbitmq-server[31810]: [1B blob data] Jul 11 15:13:40
> sk-backend-vm rabbitmq-server[31810]: Crash dump is being written to:
> /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...done Jul 11 15:13:40 sk-backend-vm
> systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE Jul 11 15:13:40 sk-backend-vm systemd[1]: Stopped
> RabbitMQ broker. Jul 11 15:13:40 sk-backend-vm systemd[1]:
> rabbitmq-server.service: Unit entered failed
```

Can you please help me here. I am so stuck.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to help. What version of RabbitMQ and Erlang? What operating system? What is in the RabbitMQ log (`/var/log/rabbitmq/...`)? What is the output of `systemctl status rabbitmq-server`? What is relevant in the output of `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: Output of `df -h` would be helpful here as well along with an indication of where your erlang install/data directory is.